# fancybox: remove href's from status bar

Tags: jquery, fancybox, href

When I hover over thumbnails, the ref to the img is continuously displayed in the lower left corner. See [here](http://i1065.photobucket.com/albums/u382/hyporkas/annoying_zps3008eca9.jpg). This is distracting and I want to hide it. I think it is due to the "href's" in the gallery definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the anchor's `href` *attribute* by the special fancybox `data-fancybox-href` *attribute* like :

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-href="image01.jpg">open fancybox</a>
```

It's assumed you have properly initialized fancybox in your custom script

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L90xmgmz/1/)**

**Note**: this is for fancybox v2.x